# Why isn't my optional group greedy? /(5)?.*/

Tags: python, regex

I thought that even though a group was optional `?`, that it would still be greedy and consume characters, *if it could*, before going to the next part of the regex.

When I specify the simplified regex `(5)?.*` versus `(5).*` (group 1 *not* optional), I see different behavior in python 2.7.6, even though I would expect the same behavior using the exact same string:

```
>>> import re
>>> s = 'before [5.5s] after'
>>> r = re.compile(r'(5)?.*')
>>> print r.search(s).groups()
(None,)

>>> r2 = re.compile(r'(5).*')
>>> print r2.search(s).groups()
('5',)
```

What am I not getting?  Why is the first regex, `r`, not sucking up a 5?

*Note: I need the theory of **why**, as any attempt at solving **this** particular regex won't help me. This is an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). I have a more complex regex and I really wish to fill in the gap of my knowledge as to **why** the optional group isn't being as greedy as I would have thought and would like.*

Comment: People will never stop asking such questions... Because `(5)?` can match an empty string, and since the regex engine parses the string from left to right, the `(5)?` matches the start of the string and `.*` matches the rest of the line.

Comment: And yet, `re.compile('(.*)(.*)').search('abc').groups()` yields `('abc', '')` . Do you know why?

Comment: `search` starts matching from the beginning of the string. If it has a match (like in these cases), other start indexes are not considered.

Comment: @RossRogers: When you address someone, use `@`+username. `(.*)(.*)` is easy: the first `.*` grabs the whole string, and the second has nothing else to grab. Read about backtracking and quantifiers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**First example:**

- Your regular expression is matched against the **entire** string `s`.
- Therefore, the first character of `s`, which is a *"b"*, is matched against `(5)?`, which doesn't result in a match. That's not a problem, however, because `(5)?` is an **optional** part of the pattern, so the regex engine matches it zero times and keeps advancing the current position in the pattern.
- The rest of the string matches the rest of the pattern, so the entire string is a match. The group `(5)` itself, however, didn't match anything, so you're seeing the `None` in your first example.

**Second example:**

- The `5` is no longer optional, so the first character of a potentially matching string has to be a *"5"*. Therefore, a potential match starts at the *"5"* after *"before ["*.
- In order to be a match, the remaining string has to match the remaining pattern `.*`, which it does.

Note that in general, [using the greedy `.*` is almost never what you want](https://blog.mariusschulz.com/2014/06/03/why-using-in-regular-expressions-is-almost-never-what-you-actually-want).

Comment: The article is interesting but the title is the worst of all times.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte I apologize. ;)

Comment: Oops, it's yours, sorry. I mean that the title may lead to the assumption that greedy quantifiers must be avoided *(when they are much faster than lazy quantifiers)*. You should write an article about the ways to avoids lazy quantifiers!

Comment: It's not about greedy quantifiers in general, it's about `.*` in particular.